# Magento still displays VAT / TAX on checkout even though disabled via admin

Tags: magento, checkout

I have Magento set up to not display VAT on checkout, but it is still adding at the total. It doesn't add it up to the total - which IS correct.

For example if I have an item that costs £5 - with 20% VAT it is £6 and this is set to show in the catalogue prices - which it does. Now on checkout this item would display as £6, then £1 VAT and then shows the total, which is £6..? Has anyone else seen this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end the only way i solved this was by removing the tax out of magento and check the box that says the prices that we submit contain tax. Not ideal.

Comment: Quite unfortunate that this was so difficult to implement you had to resort to doing this.

Answer (score 3):

To hide the tax comment out in /app/code/local/Mage/Sales/Model/Quote/Address/Total/Tax.php at the end of the file:

```
public function fetch(Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address $address)
    {
        $applied = $address->getAppliedTaxes();
        $store = $address->getQuote()->getStore();
        $amount = $address->getTaxAmount();

 /*       if (($amount!=0) || (Mage::helper('tax')->displayZeroTax($store))) {
            $address->addTotal(array(
                'code'=>$this->getCode(),
                'title'=>Mage::helper('sales')->__('Tax'),
                'full_info'=>$applied ? $applied : array(),
                'value'=>$amount
            ));
        }  */
        return $this;
    }
```

To include the tax in the shipping costs, change in /app/code/local/Mage/Sales/Model/Quote/Address/Total/Subtotal.php at the end of the file

```
public function fetch(Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address $address)
    {
        $amount = $address->getShippingAmount();
        if ($amount!=0 || $address->getShippingDescription()) {
            $address->addTotal(array(
                'code'=>$this->getCode(),
                'title'=>Mage::helper('sales')->__('Shipping & Handling').' ('.$address->getShippingDescription().')',
// OLD          'value'=>$address->getShippingAmount()
                'value'=>number_format($address->getShippingAmount() + $address->getShippingTaxAmount(), 2)
            ));
        }
        return $this;
    }
```

To include the tax in the subtotal, change in /app/code/local/Mage/Sales/Model/Quote/Address/Total/Subtotal.php at the end of the file:

```
public function fetch(Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address $address)
    {
        $address->addTotal(array(
            'code'=>$this->getCode(),
            'title'=>Mage::helper('sales')->__('Subtotal'),
// OLD      'value'=>$address->getSubtotal()
            'value'=>number_format($address->getSubtotal() + $address->getTaxAmount() - $address->getShippingTaxAmount(), 2)
        ));
        return $this;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment, but i tried this but the tax is still displaying at checkout? Really odd.

Comment: I am using version 1.4 CE ? What version are you using?

Comment: you can do this in Mage_Tax_Model_Sales_Total_Quote_Tax class for 1.5

Answer (score 2):

I have just run across the same issue on Magento 1.6.2 - I apreciate the OP no longer wants an answer, however it may assist someone else in due course.

Assuming you just want to change output, and not adjust any calculations, then we can look at adjusting the output in template files (.phtml).

This has the simple advantage in that it does not effect anything else that may use the function.

With template hints on, and visiting the cart to see the output, we see that the template in use is:

*frontend/base/default/template/tax/checkout/tax.phtml*

and

*frontend/base/default/template/tax/checkout/subtotal.phtml*

As its in base, we will make a copy of these into local (I am assuming default/default) before we make any changes - So create  frontend/default/default/template/tax/checkout/tax.phtml & frontend/default/default/template/tax/checkout/subtotal.phtml with the same content.

Then make the following edits in the files - in both cases commenting out the row currently producing output (just trace the logic if your settings are not he same as mine).

frontend/default/default/template/tax/checkout/tax.phtml (lines 46 to 55)

```
    <!--<tr <?php if ($this->helper('tax')->displayFullSummary() && $_value!=0): ?> class="summary-total" onclick="expandDetails(this, '.summary-details-<?php echo $taxIter;?>')"<?php endif; ?>>
<td style="<?php echo $_style . 'display:none;' ?>" class="a-right" colspan="<?php echo $this->getColspan(); ?>">
    <?php if ($this->helper('tax')->displayFullSummary()): ?>
        <div class="summary-collapse"><?php echo $this->getTotal()->getTitle() ?></div>
    <?php else: ?>
        <?php echo $this->getTotal()->getTitle() ?>
    <?php endif;?>
</td>
<td style="<?php echo $_style . 'display:none;' ?>" class="a-right"><?php echo $this->helper('checkout')->formatPrice($_value) ?></td>
```

-->

frontend/default/default/template/tax/checkout/subtotal.phtml (lines:48 to 57)

```
    <?php else : ?>
    <!--<tr>
<td style="<?php echo $this->getStyle() ?>" class="a-right" colspan="<?php echo $this->getColspan(); ?>">
    <?php echo $this->getTotal()->getTitle() ?>
</td>
<td style="<?php echo $this->getStyle() ?>" class="a-right">
    <?php echo $this->helper('checkout')->formatPrice($this->getTotal()->getValue()) ?>
</td>
    </tr>-->
    <?php endif;?>
```

There may be an underlying set up or logic issue to cause this output in the first place, however this method will supress the output you dont want.

Answer (score 0):

In your configuration screenshot I have seen that the prices in "shopping cart display settings" are set to be displayed including tax. If I understand you correctly, I think you should set this to "Excluding Tax" (for prices and subtotal).

Comment: Hi thanks for your response - but this is not what i want. If an item is 10 (including the tax - which is adde by magento) I want that price to be £10 everywhere... and currently it is, but in the cart my site is STILL displaying the VAT as a separate amount that magento is adding.. Please see screenshot of my cart: [link] [http://awesomescreenshot.com/0b58citc8] I think i will have to edit it out of the phtml files? But even trying the above code - does not work.